# Jquery selector for the label of a checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We can select the checked checkbox (in jQuery) as follows:

```
jQuery(:checked)
```

But how can we select the label of the checked checkbox in jQuery?

Comment: Unless you label has the for attribute pointing to the checkbox

Comment: Or you've wrapped the checkbox inside your label in which case you just look for the parent label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checkbox **doesnt** come with text ( in asp.net it **DOES**)

```
jQuery(":checked").next('span').html() //next or prev ( depends n direction)
```

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET's `CheckBox` control just generate an HTML checkbox that **doesn't** come with text, and then the text?

Comment: @BoltClock thats what ive wrote.in asp.net it DOES it cmakes checkbox and later a label with `for`

Comment: This worked great! In my case, though, my checkbox list was bound and I had to use 'label' instead of 'span'.

Answer (score 3):

Checkbox text is `label` element. Simply search it with mathces of `for` attribute:

In html it looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" />
<label for="chk">Checkbox 1</label>
```

You can find it like:

```
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']');
});
```

This will return all the checkboxes labels. Label is not required to be next or previous element near checkbox.

Comment: the for attribute can point to a ID also... you could use ´$(this).attr('name') || $(this).attr('id')´

Comment: Note that if you were wanting to get the text/string of the `label`, `.map()` will return it as a jQuery object instead of a string (even if it's a string inside `.map()`), in which case appending `.get()` should help (`.map(function() { /* stuff */ }).get()`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have this html

```
<label>Label</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> test </input>
<label>Label 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" > test 2 </input>
<label>Label 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" > test 3</input>
```

you can find the label using

```
$("input:checked").prev('label');
```

*use `.next` if you have the label after the checkbox in your html

*use `.parent` if you wrapped the checkbox in the label element

Comment: or simply use `closest()` ... (its not valid to wrap the input with the label)

Comment: you are right, is not valid but... it happens! the `.closest()` will select the label only if it is ancestor of the checkbox (from  jQuery in Action: Returns a wrapped set containing the single nearest ancestor that
matches the passed expression, if any)